# how to host a nodejs and angular project on heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, hosting

I tried to host a angular and nodejs application on heroku.
but it  give me a application error. i tried every solution but not able to resolve it.
please help me in hosting it
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxcO6.png)

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FFbn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see an error in your logs:

> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

So I am giving my answer according to this error.

Heroku dynamically assigns your app a port, so you can't set the port to a fixed number. Heroku adds the port to the env, so you can pull it from there. Switch your app listen to this:

```js
.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

at the place of

```js
.listen(5000);
```

> Please note I have used port no 5000 here. Dont be confused.